# puzzling syntax with theano

Tags: python, theano

I followed the tutorial [logistic with theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html)

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
rng = numpy.random

N = 400                                   # training sample size
feats = 784                               # number of input variables



# initialize the bias term
b = theano.shared(0., name="b")

print("Initial model:")
print(w.get_value())
print(b.get_value())

# Construct Theano expression graph
p_1 = 1 / (1 + T.exp(-T.dot(x, w) - b))   # Probability that target = 1
prediction = p_1 > 0.5                    # The prediction thresholded
xent = -y * T.log(p_1) - (1-y) * T.log(1-p_1) # Cross-entropy loss function
cost = xent.mean() + 0.01 * (w ** 2).sum()# The cost to minimize
gw, gb = T.grad(cost, [w, b])             # Compute the gradient of the cost
                                      # w.r.t weight vector w and
                                      # bias term b
                                      # (we shall return to this in a
                                      # following section of this tutorial)
```

but I don't know the code " prediction = p_1 > 0.5  " .
when p_1 > 0.5  ,prediction = True ? or else ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, saying `prediction = p_1 > 0.5` is equivalent to:

```
if p_1 > 0.5:
    prediction = True
else:
    prediction = False
```

Comment: I would say "logically equivalent to but far more readable than".

Comment: @Malvolio: not true for beginners who don't (yet) understand its meaning. OP's reading came to a screeching halt when he needed to ask this question :)

Comment: @DanCornilescu -- "readable" cannot really mean "readable to someone who does not yet understand the language".

Comment: A language is not learned as taking a pill - everything at once. Also - readability is a subjective matter, often debated even between individuals with similar undestanding of the language. I'll stop here.